# How do i get row keys / cell values & call a method when a row is selected in the standard .net 2.0 Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, .net-2.0, grid

I have standard .net 2.0 gridview control from which i want to get row keys or cell values from the grid when a row is selected.

I also need to call a method each time a row is selected.

Does anybody know How i can do this using ASP.net & VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean selection by the Select command. That fires a SelectedIndexChanged event. and from there on you have the SelectedDataKey.Value (or .Values) for the Key.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
            ByVal e As EventArgs) _
            Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim key As Object = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i did this and it almost works... when i step through the code it does seem to capture the key values but then gives this error message

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

any idea whats wrong?

Comment: any idea whats wrong? -- not until you tell us which object is null.

Comment: it doesnt say... heres the code i have put in the SelectedIndexChangedMethod... 

Dim key As Object = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value
        txtTest.Text = key

Comment: You have a debugger, it can tell you who is null. Do a check on key is Nothing, it could sometimes be Null. If it is always null there is another problem.

Comment: The problem i was having was that i was dynamically setting the Data property of the XMLdatasource but had set the gridview EnableViewState Property to false. This some sort of internal problem within the Gridview which fixed itself when i set the EnableViewState to true.

Comment: Ok, but keep an eye on the size of your viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button or link button to your gridView.

For the command name put in "Select"

In the designer window, double click your gridView and your selected index changed method will be automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using third-party grid like the [Telerik one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) which allows server and client selection as well as postback on click to process some logic.

Dick